# Why would running WebGL app in Edge improve performance in Firefox?

Tags: unity, webgl, browser-based-games, browser, unity-webgl

I have a WebGL app (built using Unity 2019) which I'm testing locally in Firefox and Edge. If the app is only running in a tab in Firefox, it runs at 25 - 50 fps and has noticeable stutter. If I run the app in Firefox and Edge at the same time (each browser on its own monitor), the performance in Firefox significantly improves - it jumps up to 50 - 60 fps and stutter is eliminated.

Frankly, the results sound ridiculous even to me, but I've tested it over and over and it's 100% consistent. Opening the app in a tab in Edge immediately improves performance in Firefox. Closing the tab in Edge immediately reduces performance in Firefox.

I'm on Windows 10 with a GTX 2070 Super.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about solving a specific Game Development problem.
The question is about the way browsers preform and interact.

Comment: @AturSams Performance is a very important subject in game development. Understanding the forces at play helps us build a better/more stable game, and also helps us providing troubleshooting for our players.

Comment: In this case, rebooting the system resolved the issue. I wish I knew the underlying cause, but it looks like that will remain a mystery.

Comment: Hi, this is a long stretch. The question is about specific browsers and a specific OS with a specific hardware configuration. Even if you ran multiple different apps on these two browsers, on multiple PCs with both Windows and Linux, it would still be a highly specific question about these browsers' versions and WebGL.

It is not for instance a question about optimizing performance in your game with a code example that supposedly slows it down. You are curious about the browsers and how they interact with the system memory and resources and affect one another. It is not a good fit for gdse.